# My linked list library isn't working

Tags: c, memory

I just started learning c and I want to make my own library for using linked lists, for the moment I just need it to work with strings but I can't get it to work. I get a segmentation fault, I know it's probably a dumb mistake but I can't find it, can anyone help me?

This is the header file

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

// node structure
typedef struct _node
{
    char *data;
    struct _node *next;    
} node;

void append(node *head, char* strd);

void insert(node *head, char* strd);

void del(node *head, char* strd);

void display(node *head);

int lenght(node *head);

int search(node *head, char* strd);

void freel(node *head);  

#endif
```

Here is the .c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

void append(node *head, char* strd)
{
    node *temp, *aux;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = malloc(strlen(strd) + 1);
    strcpy(temp->data, strd);
    aux = head;
    while(aux->next != NULL)
        aux = aux->next;
    aux->next = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
}

void insert(node *head, char* strd)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = malloc(strlen(strd) + 1);
    strcpy(temp->data, strd);
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
}

void del(node *head, char* strd)
{
    node *temp, *aux;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->data, strd) == 0)
        {
            if(head == temp)
            {
                head = temp->next;
                free(temp->data);
                free(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                aux->next = temp->next;
                free(temp->data);
                free(temp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            aux = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void display(node *head)
{
    node *aux;
    aux = head;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", aux->data);
        aux = aux->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int lenght(node *head)
{
    int c = 0;
    node *aux;
    aux = head;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux->next;
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}

int search(node *head, char* strd)
{
    node *aux;
    aux = head;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(aux->data, strd) == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void freel(node *head)
{
    node *aux, *prev;
    aux = head;
    prev = aux;
    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux->next;
        free(prev->data);
        free(prev);
        prev = aux;
    }
}
```

I used this to test the library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "testing";
    char *str2 = "hello";
    char name[50];
    printf("what's your name: ");
    scanf("%49s",name);
    node *head;
    head = NULL;
    insert(head, str);
    append(head, str2);
    append(head, name);
    display(head);
    freel(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through a debugger with your code to see where the segmentation fault occurs?  Part of learning `C` is learning to debug where segmentation faults occur.

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning to use gdb.

Answer (score 3):

`head` is always `NULL` because you never assign anything else to it. The assignments in `insert` are to a different variable with the same name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize I was making a copy of head and never returning anything.